# Print panel accessory view shows in OS X 10.11, but not in 10.10 and 10.9

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsviewcontroller, nsprintpanel

My OS X app supports 10.9 - 10.11. I try to add some options to a printing operation by adding a print accessory view like this:

```
MyPrintView *printView = [[MyPrintView alloc] initWithData: [self myData]];
NSPrintOperation *printOperation = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView: printView];
NSPrintPanel *printPanel = [printOperation printPanel];
[printPanel addAccessoryController:[[MyPrintAccessory alloc] init]];
if (printOperation)
{
    [printOperation runOperationModalForWindow:_window delegate:_window didRunSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];
}
```

The accessory view is defined by a controller

```
@interface MyPrintAccessory : NSViewController <NSPrintPanelAccessorizing>
```

and a view defined in a xib file.

**All works perfectly as expected in El Capitan**, but in Yosemite and Mavericks while the print panel let's me choose my accessory in the pop-up button, if I choose it, nothing is displayed, the space where the accessory view should be displayed remains empty. No error messages are generated neither at compile nor at runtime.

Does anybody have a hint on how to solve this, or a hint, how to search for the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: When you say "No error messages are generated neither at compile nor at runtime", does that include looking at the system log using *Console.app*?

Comment: Yes, no messages on Console.app either.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by setting the option "Use Auto Layout" to off of my print accessory view nib file.

Answer (score 0):

My application does the same thing, and works in 10.10

There is a slight difference, but to preface:
My application is an `NSDocument`-based application.
When printing, I grab the `NSPrintInfo` from the `NSDocument`, and feed it to my print method (the code you have embedded in your question)

Looks like this:

```
[printView requestPrintWithPrintInfo:[doc printInfo]];
```

Then, instead of calling `-printOperationWithView:`, I call `-printOperationWithView:printInfo:`, and I pass the `printInfo` that came from the sender

From Apple's docs, you should call `-printOperationWithView` when:

> /* Slight conveniences, for use when the application's global NSPrintInfo is appropriate. Each of these methods invokes [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo] and then invokes the like-named method listed above.

To me it sounds like it should work anyways, but like I said that's seemingly the only difference in our code

Comment: Have you investigated if the nib/xib is loaded correctly? Because I think before 10.10 you have to either name it explicitly via `(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)bundle` or override the initializer in your NSViewController subclass accordingly.